# boost xml parsingl send a path of xml as variable

Tags: c++, boost, xml-parsing

`read_xml()` function get a parameter of xml name and `ptree` member, but i want to send file's file directory such as `C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\Desktop\ddd.xml` as a variable. When i tried to do that it gives me error that cannot open file. How can i send file directory as a variable ?

My example code like this

```
ptree pt;
    try
    {
        read_xml("C:\\Users\serhan.erkovan\Desktop\ddd.xml", pt);
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error &ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what();
    }
```

Working example like this

```
ptree pt;
    try
    {
        read_xml("ddd.xml", pt);
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error &ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what();
    }
```

Comment: Use / in Windows instead of \. If you really want to use \, use \\ instead.

Comment: Working form is `C:\\Users/serhan.erkovan/Desktop/ddd.xml ` . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working form is `C:\\Users/serhan.erkovan/Desktop/ddd.xml` as mentioned @Gupta and working example like this

```
ptree pt;
    try
    {
        read_xml("C:\\Users/serhan.erkovan/Desktop/ddd.xml", pt);
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error &ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what();
    }
```